# 'Cooperate' or 'Cooperate with each other'?

Tags: grammaticality, vocabulary

I would like to know if it is necessary to add "with each other" after the word "Cooperate'. Grammarly suggests that 'with each other' be removed because it is tautologous. However, I am not so sure because in some websites I see 'with each other' added.

So which one is better?

> Different parts cooperate with each other.

OR

> Different parts cooperate.

Comment: "Coperate" is wrong for sure.

Comment: You could extend the principle of simplification even further, and say that "different parts" is redundant in this sense. You can't really have the *same* parts cooperating. If you go along with that, then it should just be **parts cooperate**. But this is all stylistic. The extra words, even if redundant, can provide emphasis and clearer meaning.

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to add "with each other" to distinguish from cooperating with third parties.